# How to split a list by string

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have several large lists of strings. I need to split all of those lists into two lists so that I keep only the 2nd list. For example:

```
lst = ['This is a list', 'of strings', 'blahblahblah', 'split_here', 'something else', 'we like cake', 'aardvarks']
```

I want to grab only the strings after 'split_here' so that the new list will be this:

```
new_lst = ['something else', 'we like cake', 'aardvarks']
```

I tried this:

```
new_list = str(lst).split('split_here')[1]
```

But the new output has a bunch of escape characters (the "\" symbol). I tried replacing them with:

```
.replace('\\', '')
```

But that didn't work either.

I'm thinking there has to be a simple way to do this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for list operations, not for string operations. We just need to find the position where the separator string appears, and take a slice starting from the next element, like this:

```
lst = ['This is a list', 'of strings', 'blahblahblah', 'split_here', 'something else', 'we like cake', 'aardvarks']
new_list = lst[lst.index('split_here')+1:]
```

The above assumes that the separator string is present in the list, otherwise we'll get a `ValueError`. The result is as expected:

```
new_list
=> ['something else', 'we like cake', 'aardvarks']
```

Comment: Thank you! That was much simpler than the things I was trying out. :)

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok Please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Using [`list#index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54502149/6419007) is probably the cleanest solution.

Still, since you were trying to find a solution with strings and split, you could use:

```
'#'.join(lst).split('split_here#')[-1].split('#')
```

Note that it only works if you're sure that `#` never appears in your strings.

Here are the steps shown in the console:

```
>>> lst = ['This is a list', 'of strings', 'blahblahblah', 'split_here', 'something else', 'we like cake', 'aardvarks']
>>> '#'.join(lst)
'This is a list#of strings#blahblahblah#split_here#something else#we like cake#aardvarks'
>>> '#'.join(lst).split('split_here#')
['This is a list#of strings#blahblahblah#', 'something else#we like cake#aardvarks']
>>> '#'.join(lst).split('split_here#')[-1]
'something else#we like cake#aardvarks'
>>> '#'.join(lst).split('split_here#')[-1].split('#')
['something else', 'we like cake', 'aardvarks']
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Oscar answer, You can use `itertools.dropwhile()` too:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

lst = ['This is a list', 'of strings', 'blahblahblah', 'split_here', 'something else', 'we like cake', 'aardvarks']
new_list = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x != 'split_here',lst))[1:]
```